# ImportError: cannot import name 'online' from 'rasa_core.training'

Tags: python, cmd, rasa-core, rasa

I am following code from a book and run into this error while trying to run online training.

the full error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "train_online.py", line 9, in 
>       from rasa_core.training import online
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'online' from 'rasa_core.training' (C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\training__init__.py)

My code is:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging

from rasa_core import utils, train
from rasa_core.training import online
from rasa_core.interpreter import NatraulLanguageInterpreter

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def train_agent(interpreter):
    return train.train_dialog_model(domain_file="horoscope_domain.yml", 
stories_file="data/stories.md", output_path="models/dialog", 
nlu_model_path=interpreter, endpoints="endpoints.yml", max_history=2, kwargs= 
{"batch_size": 50, "epochs": 200, "max_training_samples": 300})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    utils.configure_colored_logging(loglevel='DEBUG')
    nlu_model_path = "'/models/nlu/default/horoscopebot"
    interpreter = NatraulLanguageInterpreter.create(nlu_model_path)
    agent = train_agent(interpreter)
    online.serve_agent(agent)
```

Answer (score 1):

The book you are reading might have outdated code samples with an outdated version of the Rasa library.

After installing the `rasa-x` package using `pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple` and trying to run `from rasa_core.training import online` in my Python 3.6 interpreter, I got the following warning:

> UserWarning: The 'rasa_core' package has been renamed. You should change your imports to use 'rasa.core' instead.

Consider reading the new [Getting Started](https://rasa.com/docs/getting-started/) with Rasa document.

Answer (score 0):

hope it help:
**remove**

```
from rasa_core.training import online
online.serve_agent(agent)
```

**Replace by this**

```
from rasa_core.training import interactive
interactive.run_interactive_learning(agent)
```